# Masonry.js doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jquery, css, masonry

I'm entering some images dynamically, then applying the masonry plugin to them. However, the images still appear to be laying out in rows on the page with plenty of white space underneath the shorter images to make them equal to the height of the taller images. I'd like them to fit together in the masonry style. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please? Can you use masonry if you're making the html appear dynamically?

jquery:

```
$.getJSON(school + "/data.json", function(data) {
  $('.images').empty();

  var images;
  images = data.images;
  captions = data.captions;
  videos = data.videos;
  var imgCount = images.length;
  $.each(images, function(key, value) {
    var caption = data.captions[key];
    $('.images').append('<div class="img-container"><div class="myitem"><img src="' + school + '/img/' + value + '" ><div class="caption">' + caption + '</div></div></div>');
    $('.images').masonry({
      columnWidth: 300,
      itemSelector: '.img-container'
    });
  });
});
```

css:

```
.caption {
     color: lightgray;
    font-size: 90%;
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
.myitem {
    max-width: 300px; height: auto; margin: 10px;
}
.myitem img {
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Is it loading Masonry.js correctly?

Comment: @Dark Ashelin: No errors in console. I'm loading masonry in the html header.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call .masonry on the parent-element of your img-containers (therefor also outside of the $.each)

Example HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Example JS:

```
 $('#container').masonry({...});
```

Comment: on a side-note - id should be used if only needed once. You might want to make img-container a class instead

Comment: Good catch about applying masonry to the parent element. In this case, that would be $('.images'). But the layout is still in rows with white space to make the height equal.

Comment: you should call .masonry() outside of .each